# Could we unify tags [port-channel] and [etherchannel] as it appear to be the same thing

Tags: discussion

I have asked this question [what is the difference between port-channel and etherchannel](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/54628/what-is-the-difference-between-port-channel-and-etherchannel) 
 And it appear to be the same. isn't the tag combinaison a source of confusion ?

Answer (score 3):

As Cown explained in his answer, there's a difference between the two terms, although they can be related.

I don't think changing all tags to one of these two would be a good idea. Using [port-channel](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/port-channel) would not make sense for questions about platforms other than Cisco's (and very similar brands). Using [etherchannel](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etherchannel) would mean that everyone searching ofr answers using the [port-channel](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/port-channel) tag would not find their answers.

Therefor, I think it's best to keep both, and make sure that some relevant questions (like the one you linked) use *both* tags, so there's a fair chance of them being found regardless of which terms a visitor uses.